# How to save models with many-to-many relationship in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, many-to-many, ember-data

I'm stuck with this problem for so long that I think that I'm missing something obvious. Here's simplified model of my case:

There is `Patient` that has all meds that he/she takes. And there is `Medicine` that has all patients who takes it.

```
// Patient model
Yo.Patient = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    meds: DS.hasMany('medicine')
});
// Medicine model
Yo.Medicine = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    patients: DS.hasMany('patient')
});
```

I've read official manual and many resources. The last one and closest to my case was this [Toptal tutorial](http://www.toptal.com/emberjs/a-thorough-guide-to-ember-data#many-to-many-relationships). Here's what I do now:

1. Before saving new patient I'm pushing array of `Medicine` objects to `newPatient.meds`.
2. Then I save `newPatient`.
3. After save is done I'm going through array of `Medicine` objects pushing `newPatient` to each of them and saving each.

   ```
   newPatient.get('meds').pushObjects(meds);
   newPatient.save().then(function (p) {
       for (var i = 0; i < meds.length; i++) {
           meds[i].get('patients').pushObject(p);
           meds[i].save();
       };
   });
   ```

But result isn't what it meant to be.

1. Saved patient doesn't have any meds. In `POST` request to server `meds` is empty array.
2. Saved meds each has patient id in `patients`. But it always has `null` on zero position of array.

Also there already was similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624193/many-to-many-relationships-with-ember-ember-data-and-rails) on StackOverflow. But solution is not very usable. And answer is 1.5 years old which is eternity in Ember world.

**Edit**
Proposed in comments by Josh `RecordArray` as I see now cant't be used in my case. Or maybe it can, but I don't know how. I have a form for creating new patient. There's list of meds checkboxes. So I need to push only checked ones to `newPatient.meds`.

What I do now: I get ids of checked checkboxes (which equals to corresponding object id), then get `Medicine` instance for each id and put it in array. Then I try to push it in `newPatient.meds'.

Comment: Hi Nikita, one thought is you may be using `pushObject` and `save` in a somewhat unusual way. I'm not sure if `meds[i].get('patients').pushObject(p)` will actually do anything. It's more common to see `meds[i].set('patients', <full-array-value>)`.

Comment: My second thought is that I would approach this by first compiling the list of meds as a `RecordArray` (for example by using `this.store.find('medicine', <some-filter>)`. Then I would use `myPatient.set('meds', <RecordArrayFromAbove>)`.  Then I would call `serialize()` on my `newPatient` object before saving it to see how Ember intends to serialize it.  If you're not seeing the results there, keep using `console.log` until you can narrow down the specific place where something's not happening as you expect.

Comment: @JoshPadnick thank you for advice! I'm new to Ember so I'm sure there is many things I do "unusual" (wrong) way. I will try this approach and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use serializer for this issue.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458335/saving-nested-models/19556684#19556684) is answer to your question